# How to switch from Legacy Testnet into Preview / Pre Production Testnet?

Tags: cardano-node, testnet

I have previously installed node 1.33.0, and now I've upgraded my node to 1.35.0. I already have a 'db' folder when I'm using 1.33.0. If I want to switch to Preview / Pre Production configuration and environment, should I create a separate 'db' folder and download the full blockchain from the beginning, or can I use my previous 'db' folder from the Legacy Testnet? Will it cause any conflict?

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to upgrade to 1.35.3 for Preview or Preprod.
You will need the new configuration files for Preview or Preprod (https://book.world.dev.cardano.org/environments.html), and you need to delete the db folder and sync from scratch (which is very fast now, as the blockchains are small).

Comment: Thank you. I have follow-up questions:

1. Are there any `binary` or `executables` that are ready to download for MacOS, so I don't have to build using Nix?

2. What is the difference between Preview and Preprod? I read it [here](https://docs.cardano.org/cardano-testnet/getting-started) that the Preprod is still on Alonzo and not Plutus V2 updated

Comment: I don't know if you can find the binaries for MacOS.
The difference in explained in the link I gave you in the answer. And correct, preview is forked, preprod still in Alonzo.